# div по всей ширине и высоте не работает в мобильной версии

Tags: html, css

в мобильной версии, div по всей ширине и высоте не растягивается когда захожу на страницу через смартфон. На десктопе в режиме девайся в хроме все ок, а вот в мозиле все также как на смартфоне. В таких же пропорциях div как и дисплей но меньше.

```
.block-header{
    width: calc(100vw - 20px); /* эти -20пх чтобы убрать строку прокрутки */
    height: 100vh;
}

@media (min-width: 480px){ 
...
```

в медиа-запросе эту ширину высоту не трогаю

Comment: так для мобильной версии надо задать width: 100%, иначе как блок может растянуться? он и остаётся 100% - 20px

Comment: спасибо щас попробую )))